# Mongoose middleware function not returning expected result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I have created a pre-init middleware function that is meant to format a Date field in my schema.

```
StadiumSchema.pre('init', function(next, stadium) {
    let date = new Date(stadium.built);
    let built = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    stadium.built = built;

    console.log(stadium);
    console.log(built);

    next();
});
```

Within the function, it does show that stadium.built has been changed. But outside of the function that value stadium.built has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in the callback function is different as far as i remember, like:

```
StadiumSchema.pre('init', function(stadium, next) {
   let date = new Date(stadium.built);
   let built = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
   stadium.built = built;

   console.log(stadium);
   console.log(built);

   next();
});
```

btw, if you're not doing anything async job here, so you can also make it sync, like:

```
StadiumSchema.pre('init', function(stadium) {
   let date = new Date(stadium.built);
   let built = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
   stadium.built = built;

   //console.log(stadium);
   //console.log(built);
});
```

However, please refer the docs for more information.